# In what scenarios is SKPaymentTransaction.transactionIdentifier the same as the validated receipt's transaction_id?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, receipt-validation

The documentation for [`SKPaymentTransaction.transactionIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction/1411288-transactionidentifier) notes:

> This value has the same format as the transaction’s `transaction_id` in
>   the receipt; however, the values may not be the same.

And the documentation for [`transaction_id`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/transaction_id) notes:

> This value has the same format as the transaction’s
>   `transactionIdentifier` property; however, the values may not be the
>   same.
>
> You can use this value to:
>
> • Manage subscribers in your account
>   database. Store the `transaction_id`, `original_transaction_id`, and
>   `product_id` for each transaction, as a best practice to store
>   transaction records for each customer. App Store generates a new value
>   for `transaction_id` every time the subscription automatically renews or
>   is restored on a new device.
>
> • Differentiate a purchase transaction from
>   a restore or a renewal transaction. In a purchase transaction, the
>   `transaction_id` always matches the `original_transaction_id`. For
>   subscriptions, it indicates the first subscription purchase. For a
>   restore or renewal, the `transaction_id` does not match the
>   `original_transaction_id`. If a user restores or renews the same
>   purchase multiple times, each restore or renewal has a different
>   `transaction_id`.

Also will note the [Receipt Validation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1) (from the Documentation Archive) states under Transaction Identifier:

> This value corresponds to the transaction’s `transactionIdentifier`
>   property.

With that noted, my question is: when is the `SKPaymentTransaction.transactionIdentifier` the same value as the validated receipt's `transaction_id`, or when isn't it?

In our app we only work with consumable in-app purchases, no subscriptions. In this scenario, are these two values the same? I ask because I need to be able to record the purchase server-side along with information about the user who purchased it. See below for an explanation of the process and problem it presents.

Let’s say a user purchases a consumable product and the request to record that transaction fails because our server is down for example, so we do not call `finishTransaction:`. Now let’s say that person logs out and logs into a different user account and purchases another consumable product and again we fail to record it. There are now two consumable products in the receipt. When they launch the app next `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)` is called with two items in the `transactions` array to inform us there’s `purchased` transactions we need to finish. We need to submit the receipt to our server to record the transactions but we also need to send some additional info along with each transaction such as the user id who purchased it. This means I need to persist this info on disk with an associated `transactionIdentifier` so I can get that data later. I can send an array of user ids and the receipt to the server. But how would the backend know which transaction in the receipt matches which user id in the array? I don’t believe the `in_app` array is guaranteed to be sorted in any particular way and may not match the order of the `transactions` array provided to `paymentQueue(_:updatedTransactions:)`. So when there’s multiple transactions to be recorded, how can we properly link them so the purchase is applied to the correct user account server-side? In this scenario, is the `transactionIdentifier` available in-app guaranteed to be the same as the `transaction_id` in the validated receipt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In testing we've determined the `transactionIdentifier` is the same value as the transaction's `transaction_id` in the validated receipt for consumable purchases.

However, we are reluctant to rely on that being the case due to the note in the documentation stating it may not be the same value. So we put a fallback in place to uniquely identify a transaction using a combination of the `transaction.payment.productIdentifier` and the `transaction.transactionDate`, which is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/receipt/in_app) to correspond to the `original_purchase_date_ms` in the receipt. This allows the backend to find the correct transaction in the receipt for the information the app submitted.